# Programa ignora o primeiro scan do loop

Tags: c, loop

Basicamente eu tenho esse programa

```
int main(){
    coordenada lista1_coordenadas[3];
    coordenada lista2_coordenadas[3];

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Leia a coordenada %d da primeira lista:\n", i+1);
        printf("x: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &lista1_coordenadas[i].x);
        printf("y: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &lista1_coordenadas[i].y);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("Leia a coordenada %d da segunda lista:\n", i+1);
        printf("x: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &lista2_coordenadas[i].x);
        printf("y: ");
        scanf("%d\n", &lista2_coordenadas[i].y);
    }
    return 0;
```

Porém quando vou scanear o x da primeira coordenada da lista 1, ele ignora o primeiro scan e pede para dar input no valor de novo, e eu n sei como arrumar isso.

Aqui tá o struct q eu usei

```
typedef struct coordenada{
    int x, y;
}coordenada;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tira o \n dos scanfs. Só precisa colocá-lo caso a leitura posterior seja de caracteres ou strings.

```
     scanf("%d", &lista1_coordenadas[i].x);
```